# How to reduce table refresh time in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have one main table (e.g., `main_data`) from which the dashboard is designed or the main source of data. But for the customized slicer, I have multiple derived tables (duplicate tables) on which I have done some operations to get the data in a particular format in the slicers.

Now the challenge is while refreshing the Power BI file It is taking too long as one main table along with 15 derived tables is getting refreshed (the main data is coming from e.g., `main_data`).

Is there any way to optimize this? If it only refreshed the main table, the dashboard should work fine.

Here `application_overview` is the main table and the rest all are derived from it:
[image: In this case, application_overview is the main table]

Comment: You have option of disabling specific table load while refresh. But what if new value comes to the main_table which should be added to one of the derived table?

Comment: @mkRabbani values shown in the slicer are coming from the derived table, which is the same all the time, for plotting the graph in DAX I am using main_table. Will it work if I only refresh the main_table?

Comment: It should work that case.

Answer (score 1):

In the Report layout, select the main table then click on the three dots, there you will find the option to Refresh data, so this will refresh only your main data table.

Comment: values shown in the slicer are coming from the derived table, which is the same all the time, for plotting the graph in DAX I am using main_table. Will it work if I only refresh the main_table?